# Google Timezone API: Request Loop

Tags: lotusscript, google-maps-timezone

I have the following code that connects to google timezone api and returns a json message from which i would derive if there is an offset or not.

Question: I am using a for loop here and it returns correct message for the iteration 1 and for the next iteration it says

> { "errorMessage" : "The provided API key is invalid.", "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }"

Here is my code:

```
strArtifactoryUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?"
apiKey = "AIzaSyCoJ1l1MkioDqYQNIDn7WsZjKv_inwktYM"

LatLongStr = "40.7142700,-74.0059700~United States###51.5085300,-0.1257400~United Kingdom"  

Set session = New NotesSession

latVar = Split(LatLongStr,"###")
ForAll lv In latVar
    If CStr(lv) <> "" Then                      
        REM location based on latitude and longitude        
        strArtifactoryUrl =  strArtifactoryUrl + "location=" +StrLeft(CStr(lv),"~")

        REM UTC timestamp
        Set usD = New NotesDateTime("12/01/2014 00:00:00")
        Call usD.Adjustday(3)       
        strArtifactoryUrl = strArtifactoryUrl + "&timestamp=" +CStr(getTimeStamp(usD.Lslocaltime)) &"&key=" & apiKey
        c = StrRight(CStr(lv),"~")

        Set httpObject = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") 
        Call httpObject.open("GET", strArtifactoryUrl, False)
        Call httpObject.Send()

        Print httpObject.responseText
  End If
End forall

Function getTimeStamp(dt As Variant) As Long
  Dim dtEpoch As New NotesDateTime("1/1/1970 00:00:00")
  Dim dtTemp As New NotesDateTime(Now)
  dtTemp.LSLocalTime = dt
  getTimeStamp = dtTemp.TimeDifference(dtEpoch)
End Function
```

I used a sample date. My aim is to run this every day notify people 3 days in advance. Appreciate your inputs. You can use the API key to try at your as it a free account.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: you don't reset the variable `strArtifactoryUrl` after the first run, and therefor append another location and another timestamp on every run, rendering the url useless.

Define another variable called `strBaseUrl` and form the variable `strArtifactoryUrl` from that in the line where you append the location.

This would be the resulting code:

```
strBaseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?"
apiKey = "AIzaSyCoJ1l1MkioDqYQNIDn7WsZjKv_inwktYM"

LatLongStr = "40.7142700,-74.0059700~United States###51.5085300,-0.1257400~United Kingdom"  

Set session = New NotesSession

latVar = Split(LatLongStr,"###")
ForAll lv In latVar
    If CStr(lv) <> "" Then                      
        REM location based on latitude and longitude        
        strArtifactoryUrl =  strBaseUrl + "location=" +StrLeft(CStr(lv),"~")

        REM UTC timestamp
        Set usD = New NotesDateTime("12/01/2014 00:00:00")
        Call usD.Adjustday(3)       
        strArtifactoryUrl = strArtifactoryUrl + "&timestamp=" + _
            CStr(getTimeStamp(usD.Lslocaltime)) &"&key=" & apiKey
        c = StrRight(CStr(lv),"~")

        Set httpObject = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") 
        Call httpObject.open("GET", strArtifactoryUrl, False)
        Call httpObject.Send()

        Print httpObject.responseText
  End If
End forall
```

Comment: Agreed. Missed that silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.